# List of actual GPS position

Tags: gps, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I have a question - where can I find a list of actual GPS position, for example - ships, airplanes etc.

I need it for my project for College - I will create mobile/desktop/web app, which will show on map current positions of this elements, their last road and save info about that elements in database.

Also, is there any website with informations about weather problems with lat/lng info?

Thanks in advance, I've tried to find something about it, but without result..

Comment: I don't think that exists/ you will be able to get access to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this http://www.sea-seek.com/tracks/list_ships.php?ong=22 ? Not sure if this is it